# Can wizards tunnel under a shielded area?

Tags: harry-potter

Can wizards tunnel under a shielded area?
For example, can wizards tunnel under an area of land outside a shielded area, and walk a certain distance then destroy the piece of land above you, and then use a way to get up (like making a ladder appear out of thin air, broomstick, then reappear inside the shielded area? There isn't any proof that the underground portion of the land that is shielded is protected by the shield.

Comment: "*IRMA, dead on the floor, and NAGINI, who backs away from him. Slowly, his grin fading, GRIMMSON looks up at the ceiling. The Obscurus is swirling there like thick black smoke. In a flash, GRIMMSON conjures a domed Shield Charm around himself and IRMA’S body. And the Obscurus dives, pelting the Shield Charm like a million bullets, rising and re-forming and diving again, but though the magical barrier trembles, it is not broken.* - Crimes of Grindlewald screenplay book

Comment: @Valorum that's a domed shield charm. It is not known if all shielded areas, like Hermione's and Harry's during their search for Horcruxes includes the unseen, underground portion.

Comment: This is a highly specific question that has no answer in the Harry Potter canon. It *might* be possible for some spells and not others. As you said, there isn't any proof that the underground portion of the land is also shielded, but we simply don't know.